# Django WSGI APACHE ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django, apache

its been a nightmare trying to deploy django using apache and wsgi on ubuntu server 18, I created a virtual environment, installed dependencies, restarted apache many times however apache wsgi cant find django in my virtual environment.
I can run manage.py runserver so virtual environment dependencies are ok.
My python version for venv is 3.8

this is apache error log:

```
[Sun Dec 08 02:09:53.028651 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 18902:tid 140235766351616] [remote 186.116.79.225:59496]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Sun Dec 08 02:09:53.028666 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 18902:tid 140235766351616] [remote 186.116.79.225:59496] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
[Sun Dec 08 02:09:53.335770 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 18902:tid 140235648796416] [remote 186.116.79.225:59497] mod_wsgi (pid=18902): Target WSGI script '/var/www/iotconfigserver/IOT_config_rest/IOT_config_rest/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Dec 08 02:09:53.335820 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 18902:tid 140235648796416] [remote 186.116.79.225:59497] mod_wsgi (pid=18902): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/iotconfigserver/IOT_config_rest/IOT_config_rest/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Dec 08 02:09:53.335893 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 18902:tid 140235648796416] [remote 186.116.79.225:59497] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Dec 08 02:09:53.335915 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 18902:tid 140235648796416] [remote 186.116.79.225:59497]   File "/var/www/iotconfigserver/IOT_config_rest/IOT_config_rest/wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
[Sun Dec 08 02:09:53.335919 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 18902:tid 140235648796416] [remote 186.116.79.225:59497]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Sun Dec 08 02:09:53.335933 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 18902:tid 140235648796416] [remote 186.116.79.225:59497] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
[Sun Dec 08 02:09:53.665977 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 18902:tid 140235766351616] [remote 186.116.79.225:59498] mod_wsgi (pid=18902): Target WSGI script '/var/www/iotconfigserver/IOT_config_rest/IOT_config_rest/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Dec 08 02:09:53.666021 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 18902:tid 140235766351616] [remote 186.116.79.225:59498] mod_wsgi (pid=18902): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/iotconfigserver/IOT_config_rest/IOT_config_rest/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Dec 08 02:09:53.666097 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 18902:tid 140235766351616] [remote 186.116.79.225:59498] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Dec 08 02:09:53.666120 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 18902:tid 140235766351616] [remote 186.116.79.225:59498]   File "/var/www/iotconfigserver/IOT_config_rest/IOT_config_rest/wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
[Sun Dec 08 02:09:53.666124 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 18902:tid 140235766351616] [remote 186.116.79.225:59498]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Sun Dec 08 02:09:53.666139 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 18902:tid 140235766351616] [remote 186.116.79.225:59498] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

I don't know what to do,

this is my /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        Alias /static /var/www/iotconfigserver/IOT_config_rest/static

        <Directory /var/www/iotconfigserver/IOT_config_rest/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/iotconfigserver/IOT_config_rest/IOT_config_rest >
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess IOT_config_rest python-home=/var/www/iotconfigserver/venv python-path=/var/www/iotconfigserver/IOT_config_r$        
    WSGIProcessGroup IOT_config_rest
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/iotconfigserver/IOT_config_rest/IOT_config_rest/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

thanks to anyone trying to help

Comment: were you ever able to fix this, looks like the comment below mentioned that you would need to build the mod_wsgi module with 3.8 instead of 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

I could deploy by downgrading python venv to 3.6, but I still don't know why

Comment: This is because the mod_wsgi module was compiled with python3.6 and therefore uses the python3.6 library (in which django isn't installed) not the venv which runs on py3.8